# How to handle API call error with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a weather app as a school project. I have an input through which the user is supposed to enter a name of a city to get the weather from an API. If the user misspells the name of the city I get an error in the console. I'd like to catch this when it happens and display some message to inform the user to correct the input. I searched other questions on StackOverflow and jQuery site as well, but didn't get my answer so that's why I'm here.

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + valueFromInput + '&units=metric&type=like&mode=json&APPID=cdb7ecf86aa724f19f723f964e5f15ae',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (weatherData) {...//code}
```

I tried putting the ajax inside a try/catch block and added error: function().. beneath success, it still doesn't display an error message.

Why isn't this working? Is this easier to do in plain javascript?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I wrote that it isn't working if I add error argument.
The error is this:



app.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.success (app.js:40)
    at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
    at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)

Comment: Nothing shown would generate that error. In browser dev tools network inspect the response when input doesn't resolve and provide more details. My guess is they return a response object with error properties in it you need to look for. Also the status

Comment: @Shepherd What is the code that you have in your success function? It sounds like the ajax is successful and getting to your success function then breaking.

Comment: Since you already exposed your api key...create a demo that reproduces problem. Not a good idea exposing api keys here BTW

Comment: it's a lot of these:   

            divDetails.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<h2 id='cityNameCountry_'></h2>");
            document.getElementById("cityNameCountry_").appendChild(document.createTextNode((weatherData.list[0].name)));

Comment: OK and when list is empty that last line is the error. Check list length first , or check count

Comment: @Shepherd if your list is empty you will get the error from this `weatherData.list[0].name`

Comment: Okay I see it now. thank you very much both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if statement to your success function to check if the list has elements in it. Otherwise you will get an error trying to get the name of an element that doesn't exist.

```
success: function (weatherData) {
    if (weatherData.list.length > 0)  
        document.getElementById("cityNameCountry_").appendChild(document.createTextNode((weatherData.list[0].name)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems that you go and use this:

```
weatherData.list[0].name
```

your response as you mentioned is like this

```
"message":"like","cod":"200","count":0,"list":[]
```

You should check your response in order to see if you have any server errors.

My guess from what you have provided seems like you don't take into consideration neither the response code nor the number of items. You should change your ajax success handler to something like the following.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + valueFromInput + '&units=metric&type=like&mode=json&APPID=cdb7ecf86aa724f19f723f964e5f15ae',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        // Error handling
        if (result.code != '200'){
            alert('some kind of error');
            return false;
        }

        // Checking the number of list items
        if (result.list.length > 0){
                   document.getElementById("cityNameCountry_").appendChild(document.createTextNode((result.list[0].name)));
        }  
    }

});
```